# Python Threading

Tags: python, multithreading

I have the code below that I am using to thread certain tasks. Basically, you pass in a function reference, a list of data and the number of threads. It will run the function for each item in the list with the specified number of threads.

I currently have this in a separate py file that I import as needed. Performance has been kind of strange and inconsistent though. What do you guys think?

```
import threading
import logging
import threading
import time
from queue import Queue

def thread_proc(func,data,threads):
    if threads < 0:
        return "Thead Count not specified"
    q = Queue()

    for i in range(threads):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_exec,args=(func,q))
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

    for item in data:
        q.put(item)

    logging.debug('*** Main thread waiting')
    s = q.qsize()
    while s > 0:
        logging.debug("Queue Size is:" + str(s))
        s = q.qsize()
        time.sleep(1)
    logging.debug('*** Main thread waiting')
    q.join()
    logging.debug('*** Done')

def thread_exec(func,q):
    while True:
        d = q.get()
        #logging.debug("Working...")
        try:
            func(d)
        except:
            pass
        q.task_done()
```

Comment: Threads don't provide much benefit for many applications because they contend for Python's [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). But if you really want to use a pool of threads in Python, there's [`multiprocessing.dummy.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) which is just like [`multiprocessing.pool.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) but with threads instead of processes.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by: *"Performance has been kind of strange and inconsistent though."*

Comment: I was expecting a more linear performance increase by pushing certain processing through this threading function, but it was not so, even with estimation for thread starting overhead. So if there is no multithreading in python because of GIL, what is the point of this module?

Comment: Modules implemented in C release the GIL when they do not need it, for example during I/O or socket operations. So if your threads are mostly doing these kinds of operations, then they don't contend for the GIL and so spend more time running in parallel.

Answer (score 4):

This code very very similar to the example in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).
As such, it looks fine, I can only suggest coding style improvements.

---

This is a bit strange:

> ```
> def thread_proc(func,data,threads):
>     if threads < 0:
>         return "Thead Count not specified"
> ```

It's not really true that "thread count is not specified",
since the parameter `threads` is there,
and apparently not `None`.
Maybe the message should be "invalid thread count".

More importantly, didn't you mean the condition as `threads < 1` ?

---

> ```
> for i in range(threads):
>     # ...
> ```

When you don't need the iterator variable inside the loop, it's customary to call it `_`. That way I won't be looking inside the loop body for a variable `i` that's not there:

```
for _ in range(threads):
    # ...
```

And while we talk about naming, the example in the docs used `item = q.get()`, but you changed to `d = q.get()`. Although `item` maybe a bit too generic name, `d` is definitely worse.

#### PEP8

You're not following [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). There are several violations.

Put a space after commas in parameter lists, for example instead of this:

> ```
> def thread_proc(func,data,threads):
> ```

Write like this:

```
def thread_proc(func, data, threads):
```

---

Similarly, here:

> ```
> thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_exec,args=(func,q))
> ```

Write like this:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_exec, args=(func,q))
```

And you should put two empty lines before function declarations.